# Javascript function not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a project for school and my Javascript suddenly stopped showing up. can anyone tell me what's going on?

I'm talking about the scroll back to top button that should appear at the bottom right corner.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u67cea52/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function showItem(evt, itemName) {
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active",     "");
}
document.getElementById(itemName).style.display = "block";
evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
$(document).ready(function(){

//kijkt of je verder bent dan de cover pagina, zoja dan verschijnt de knop
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

//het event wat ervoor zorgt dat als je op de knop klikt dat je weer     naar boven gaat
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
        return false;
});

});
});
```

Comment: could you show your HTML and CSS ( relevant ) . that could be the problem

Comment: here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u67cea52/

Comment: Just placing a comment before I check the code further. Since there is only one button to scroll back to top, why don't you use `id` attribute? `class` is for interacting with 1+ elements. It also would make the things more easier.

Comment: Your fiddle is missing external resources. Could you please include the stylesheets and scripts you are linking to? There is a panel on the left where you can do so.

Comment: Also, you have an anchor tag in the `head` of your page, that is invalid HTML.

Comment: all my css/js/html is in the fields already?

Comment: firstly your `.scrollToTop` element should have `bottom` set instead of `top`. That makes it always stick/dock to the bottom, so you will surely see it when it's shown. If setting `top` instead, when the screen/window's heigh t is less than your set value (which is `768px`), you will never see it. Secondly ensure that your `.scrollToTop` has some matter to be rendered. From your demo, looks like the `fa` is missing, so nothing is shown. I had to add a solid background instead to see it working. Check out this adjusted demo https://jsfiddle.net/u67cea52/2/

Comment: please take some time to find more about jsfiddle or any other online fiddle (to help play with HTML and javascript quickly). You don't know how to create a good fiddle, your fiddle has some js references but they are included with ***relative*** paths, which won't work.

Comment: thanks King King, that fixed my problem. got a new one now tho, the tab buttons dont work anymore. and yea i never use jsfiddle but I needed to show my code somehow..

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">Hello World</div>
<a href="#" id="back-to-top" title="Back to top">&uarr;</a>
```

CSS:

```
#back-to-top {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 40px;
    right: 40px;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
#back-to-top:hover {
    background: #e9ebec;
}
#back-to-top.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
#content {
    height: 2000px;
}
```

JS:

```
if ($('#back-to-top').length) {
    var scrollTrigger = 100, // px
        backToTop = function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            if (scrollTop > scrollTrigger) {
                $('#back-to-top').addClass('show');
            } else {
                $('#back-to-top').removeClass('show');
            }
        };
    backToTop();
    $(window).on('scroll', function () {
        backToTop();
    });
    $('#back-to-top').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 700);
    });
}
```